# Auditing an entity using Spring/hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a table T_TEST .And i have created a entity for it.I need to audit all the DBL operation on this entity in T_TEST_AUDIT.

How can i do it.

I am using Sprng-boot/Hibernate .
I went through lot of online tutorial and tried to implement it but none worked for my scenario

I went through lot of online tutorial and tried to implement it but none worked for my scenario.

I am only able to insert records in T_TEST  but not in T_TEST_AUDIT

```
CREATE TABLE T_TEST 
(
ID NUMBER ,
EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(200),
SAL NUMBER,
MODIFICATION_DATE DATE,
CREATE_DATE DATE,
CREATED_BY VARCHAR2(200),
APPROVED_BY VARCHAR2(200)
);



CREATE TABLE T_TEST_AUDIT
(
AUDIT_ID NUMBER ,
ID NUMBER ,
EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(200),
SAL NUMBER,
MODIFICATION_DATE DATE,
CREATE_DATE DATE,
CREATED_BY VARCHAR2(200),
APPROVED_BY VARCHAR2(200)
);
```

Comment: you ,ay use hibernate envers or JPA listeners. More information here https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa

Comment: i have already seen the link but it didnt work..i am only able to populate T_TEST table

Comment: What dod you use? Envers?

Comment: Have you tried @Audited  annotation. // that's the important part :) 

visit quickstart section at https://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/

Comment: that baeldung tutorial.I was getting errors

Answer (score 2):

Use [hibernate-envers](https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/). It is really easy to integrate. The entities which you wish to audit, i.e. maintain history for will be annotated with `@Audited`. Hibernate will create a separate audit table and insert a row in it for every update/insert/delete.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Example:

```
@Audited
public class Zoo implements Serializable {

  private String name;
  private String address;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "zoo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
  @NotAudited // incase you don't any field to be audited, annotate them with @NotAudited
  private List<Animals> animals;

  }
```

Comment: can you give the sample code for the above example i posted.which entity i need to add @Audited

Comment: If you have `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` set to update in your `application.properties`, you don't have to create the audit table yourself, hibernate will create it for you if your entity class is annotated with `@Audited`

Comment: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

Comment: in my app.properties 

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

Will this work

Comment: Try changing it to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` and see tables will be created.